# Angular js output event emitter method not getting called

Tags: angular, angular-event-emitter

The method triggered through output event emitter is not getting called.
This is my output event emitter:

```
 @Output() onEditTask: EventEmitter<Task> = new EventEmitter();
```

This is my view:

```
<app-add-task (onAddTask)="addTask($event)" (onEditTask)="editTask($event)"></app-add-task>
```

This method doesnt get called:

```
  editTask(task: Task) {
    debugger;
  }
```

Comment: This is how im emitting:
      const editTaskVal = {
        text: this.task.text,
        day: this.task.day,
        reminder: this.task.reminder
      };
      this.onEditTask.emit(editTaskVal);

Comment: Where are you calling ` this.onEditTask.emit(editTaskVal);`? In the constructor?

Comment: No, on a button click

Comment: Please show your button element with click event on how you emit as mentioned in the first comment. Thanks.

Comment: @YongShun

onSubmit() {
      debugger;
      const editTaskVal = {
        text: this.task.text,
        day: this.task.day,
        reminder: this.task.reminder
      };

      debugger;
      this.onEditTask.emit(editTaskVal);
  }

Comment: Cannot reproduce your issue, I can see it works: [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dkitpk?file=src/app/add-task/add-task.component.ts). Can you try to reproduce the issue in StackBlitz? Thanks.